# Best way to handle filtering with multiple fields

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, dataview

All of the variables are here, I'm just not what the syntax should be.

I'm trying to create a drop down searchbox filter. The search box fields are dynamically populated using the code below

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Vwr.Table.Vals, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Col}" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBlock}"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Val}" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBox}" Width="200"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CTStr}" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBlock}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

**Col** : the column name

**Val** : the value inside of the textbox

**CTStr** : The dataType

---

The syntax for a RowFilter in c# is something like below ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx))

"**Col** LIKE '%" + **Val** + "%' + " AND " + "**Col** LIKE '%" + **Val** + "%' 
 ... "

So what i need to do, is call an ICommand that launches whenever one of these dynamically generated textfields is updated, that when called checks to see the current RowFilter string, then, if it already has a field filtering in it appends AND and then it's own filter string.

Would it be possible to set the textbox to launch an ICommand with Col and the value inside of the textbox as command parameters anytime the user edits the textbox field?

Another solution i was thinking of was to somehow get the textbox into the scope of Vwr.Table where the DataView is stored. (Currently it's source is bound to Vwr.Table.Vals) From there I would bind it to a string that updated the dataview like so,

```
public string Filter
{
    get { return _Filter; }
    set
    {
        _Filter = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Filter));
        MainVM.Modules.AllModules[0].Vwr.Table.dv.RowFilter = Col + " LIKE '%" + _Filter + "%'";
    }
}
private string _Filter = "";
```

another

Comment: Before I attempt to answer this, I have to understand why are you using DataTable stuff with WPF? Why not EF? I also hope you do some input sanity checks before you pass it in like this!

Comment: That's good advice! I've figured this out. i'll post my answer soon

Answer (score 1):

The key to this was passing the DataTemplate Item as the command parameter. As well as using relativeSource to get the data where it needed to go.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Vwr.Table.Vals, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="Item">
            <TextBlock x:Name="SearchCol" Text="{Binding Col}" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBlock}"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="SearchText" Text="{Binding Filter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.Modules.SelectedModule.Vwr.Table.FilterCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                     AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Item, Path=DataContext}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBox>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CTStr}" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBlock}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I use this code to get the context i need, send the entire dataItem as the command parameter and then parse that data into a list of strings. I then called `RowFilter = string.join( " AND " , FilterList.ToArray())` to connect them all;

Comment: This may have worked for you but it's an extremely convoluted design you've got going on and there's definitely easier ways of doing things. It's sad that this is a wasted bounty since nobody else can actually use this answer in their own projects.